# Will it be possible to buy shares online using bitcoins in a financial market?

Tags: funds

Do you foresee people one day people trading  securities,bonds,stocks or currencies with bitcoins.I would like to buy a share lets say from Microsoft with bitcoins and have the value of it remain in  bitcoins instead of normal currency.

Will that be feasible?

Are there any sites or tor sites that offer such a platform.If so could you provide me with the such link.

Thanks.

Comment: Likely, but this is a speculative answer.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that can be done with a traditional currency can be done with Bitcoin. Be it buying groceries, shares, stocks, bonds, or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

> "I would like to buy a share lets say from Microsoft with bitcoins and have the value of it remain in bitcoins instead of normal currency."

Well, in that case you would be trading MSFT/BTC, so if the value of BTC keeps rising with comparison to MSFT and you're holding MSFT, then you will lose BTC. For now it doesn't seem like it will be worthwhile to do such a thing.

Comment: If everybody knew that the value of bitcoins was always going to go up, then everybody would be buying as many as they can and the exchange rate would skyrocket. That's not happening.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular I didn't say that the value of bitcoin will **always** go up, but for now it's looking like it will continue to go up. At the end of the day it's just a matter of speculation I guess...